# Why this code runs well on ubuntu and not in Windows 8?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Yesterday during the coci(CROATIAN OPEN COMPETITION IN INFORMATICS) i had a problem with the first task that asked me to find the correct password from the given passwords list, the
correct password is the one which can be found in both the original and reverse order in the list. For example, if the word “tulipan” would be the correct password, the word “napilut” has to also appear in the list.

The first line of input contains the integer N (1 ≤ N ≤ 100), the number of possible passwords.
Each of the following N lines contains a single word, its length being an odd number greater than 2 and lesser than 14.

The first and only line of output must contain the length of the correct password and its central letter.
The solution will be unique.

```
So ex

input

4

las

god

psala

sal

output

3 a
```

There can also be a palindrome word ex: kisik that would be the correct password.

My solution was the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



using namespace std;

int main()
{
int N,i,k,j,x,w;
cin >>N;
int lung[N];
string S1[N];
string S2[N];
bool trovata=false;
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{

    cin >> S1[i];
    for(k=0; S1[i][k]!='\0'; k++);


    for(j=0; j<k; j++)
    {
        S2[i][k-j-1]=S1[i][j];
    }
    S2[i][k]='\0';
    lung[i]=k;
    int conta=0;
    for(j=0; j<k; j++)
    {
        if (S1[i][j]==S2[i][j]) conta++;

    }
    if(conta==k)
    {
        x=(k/2);
        cout <<k<<" "<<S2[i][x];
        trovata=true;
        break;
    }

}

if(trovata==false)
{
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                int conta=0;
                if(lung[i]==lung[j])
                {


                    for(w=0; w<lung[i]; w++)
                    {
                        if (S1[i][w]==S2[j][w]) conta++;

                    }
                    if(conta==lung[i])
                    {
                        x=(lung[i]/2);
                        cout <<lung[i]<<" "<<S2[i][x];

                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with CodeBlocks 13.12 on Windows 8 and the output was written twice (in the first ex i had as output "3 a3 a" instead of "3 a") but when i compiled it on C::B running on Ubuntu it gave me the right output. What's wrong in this code?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the toolchains used on *both* platforms. And note that variable length arrays in C++ are non-standard. Use a `std::vector<>` instead if you want portable code.

Comment: I think your last break will not break out of both for loops.

Comment: It was my teacher laptop so i have no informations about it (i guess it was C::B 10.xx i can't remember well sorry)

Comment: As wimmel suggested i needed another break after the first one to get out of the other loop.

Comment: `cin >> S1[i];
 for(k=0; S1[i][k]!='\0'; k++);`

Your're confused here.  A std::string is not usually null-terminated.  A std::string's length is determined by the std::string::size() function, not by a  terminating null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is overly complicated for whats it needs to do, having said that, in the case it's not a palindrome, your code will find the matching word twice and therefore print it twice. You should stop the search on finding the first match. The break will only break out of the innerloop, the outer loop will continue and it will find the reverse as well.

Comment: Yeah thanks, with the first break i got out of the first loop i had to add another one to get out of the second and get the correct output.

Comment: This does not explain why the code does output correct answer sometimes. The reason for that is UB, not an error in the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reserving space for your strings in the S2 array.  Thus `S2[i][k-j-1]=S1[i][j];` is UB, and any correct (or incorrect!) answer printed is by sheer luck.

Comment: Could you please explain better ? What you mean with "Thus S2[i][k-j-1]=S1[i][j]; is UB" ?

Comment: Do you know what is "Undefined Behavior"?

Comment: Oh got it, how could i fix it ? That piece of code was written by my teacher. When i try to output the reversed string on console i get only a black line i guess that's the error.

Comment: Get a C++ book. *Accelerated C++* is good. If I telll you that you should do `S2[i]=S1[i];` will it help? I somehow doubt that. There are many other errors here that indicate close to zero familiarity with C++. Conducting a C++ 101 here in comments is counterproductive, I won't do that.